# How to get the ID out of Braintree's JSON response?

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, paypal, braintree

I'm trying to integrate PayPal Express Checkout using Braintree SDK.

I can so far charge the Nonce returned from the client and I receive this response. However, I need to take the ID out in order to save it in a table.

My question is how do I parse the id??

```
Successful {#315
  +success: true
  -_returnObjectNames: array:1 [
    0 => "transaction"
  ]
  #_attributes: []
  +"transaction": Transaction {#324
    #_attributes: array:63 [
      "id" => "xxx"// How do I parse this out?
      "status" => "settling"
      "type" => "sale"
      "currencyIsoCode" => "USD"
      "amount" => "6.00"
```

The variable that holds this JSON is $success. Thus, I tried several things like:

```
$success->transaction->id
$success->id
```

If I do `$success->success` I get `true` and If I do `$success->transaction` I get the `Transaction` object.

Comment: Try this    $res = json_decode($response, true);  echo $response['success']['transaction']['id'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact).</sub>

If running `$success->success`returns `True` and `$success->transaction` returns the `Transaction` object, then you should be able to [query the transaction ID](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/php#id) using `$success->transaction->id`, we also demonstrate this [in our developer documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php#options.submit_for_settlement).

```
$result = $gateway->transaction()->sale([
  'amount' => '10.00',
  'paymentMethodNonce' => nonceFromTheClient,
  'options' => [
    'submitForSettlement' => True
  ]
]);

if ($result->success) {
  // See $result->transaction for details
} else {
 // Handle errors
}
```